# Why does this chunk of code breaking up a CGColor cause a Bus Error?

Tags: objective-c, calayer

Using this code causes a Bus Error. Can someone point out what is wrong with it? I'm overriding a method from CALayer.

```
- (void) setBackgroundColor:(CGColorRef)c
{
    float *components = (float *)CGColorGetComponents(c);
    [super setBackgroundColor:[LOLColors colorWithRed:components[0] green:components[1] blue:components[2] alpha:transparencyLevel]];
}
```

**P.S.** *colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha is a class method which works perfectly fine*.

That's the prototype:

```
+ (CGColorRef) colorWithRed:(float)red green:(float)green blue:(float)blue alpha:(float)alpha
```

Comment: While casting value types to other types (like `CGFloat` to `float`) should never be a problem, I'd be careful when casting pointer types to other types. If `CGFloat` is actually not the size of a `float`, you're gonna have serious problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And again, figured by trial and error.

The size of ***components** array was smaller than 2 so I was accessing non-existent members.